# Calling a function from another class?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a new java class inside android project I need to call my other class functions inside android activity.

So I have created a java class inside app/java folder my file is `Moving.java`

my code is :

```
  package edmt.dev.androidgridlayout;
  public  class Moving {
     public void move() {
         System.out.println("Animals can move");
     }
  }
```

I am trying to call move function inside my activity using this:

```
Moving a = new Moving();
a.move();
```

I am getting

> error: can't resolve move

What is the best way to create new class in android and use it in activities?

Comment: public class Test

Comment: ` test is abstract `? You are missing some part of code.

Comment: `Activity` and other source files are `.java` files in `Android` unless you're using `Kotlin`. So please first go through [basic method creation and calling in Java](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to:

1. add `public` like `public class Test ...`.
2. find if the class import is import by `import edmt.dev.androidgridlayout.Test1` or a other package.

Comment: I changed the file name to Moving and added public now I am getting error Moving a = new Moving(); this works fine but when I am trying to call  a.move(); it is saying can't resolve

Answer (score 1):

Make your `Test` class public and then create an object of this class in your activity

Comment: @user2480754 Can you post your activity class also?